# How to insert and update with particuliar condititions?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to update and insert records in a Fact Table. There is some conditions.

1) I have to update the row of the record when the record change in the same day

2) and to insert when the record is change on another date (Date_Import).

But for the moment I think there is a problem in the left join. When I run the code, it updates all the records and not only the good one.

Table : Fact

```
Fact_Key    Date_Import Date_of_Work WorkshopID  WorkforceNeeded
----------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ---------------
1           20190425    20190501     2           220
2           20190425    20190501     3           40
3           20190425    20190504     2           6
4           20190425    20190504     3           35
```

Table : Staging

```
Date_Import Date_of_Work WorkshopId  WorkforceNeeded
----------- ------------ ----------- ---------------
20190425    20190501     2           185
20190426    20190501     3           68
20190425    20190504     2           6
20190425    20190504     3           35
```

Expected result

```
Fact_Key    Date_Import Date_of_Work WorkshopID  WorkforceNeeded
----------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ---------------
1           20190425    20190501     2           185          -- updated
2           20190425    20190501     3           40
3           20190425    20190504     2           6
4           20190425    20190504     3           35
5           20190426    20190501     3           68           -- inserted
```

EDIT :

Actual Result if I run the code with this two tables :

```
Fact_Key    Date_Import Date_of_Work WorkshopID  WorkforceNeeded
----------- ----------- ------------ ----------- ---------------
1           20190425    20190501     2           185
2           20190425    20190501     2           185
3           20190425    20190501     2           185
4           20190425    20190501     2           185
5           20190425    20190501     3           40
6           20190425    20190504     2           6
7           20190425    20190504     3           35
```

Code that doesn't work totally fine

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- UPDATE (first because we update only record already in the table)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
begin
    update DWH.Fact
    set
        -- Colonne Business 
        [Date_Import] = GETDATE(),
        [WorshopId] = S.WorkshopId,
        [Date_of_Work] =  convert(int, convert(char(8), Convert(Date,S.Date_of_Work), 112)),
        [WorkforceNeeded] =  Convert(int,S.WorkforceNeeded)
    FROM Staging S
        left outer join
        (
        SELECT *
        FROM    (
            SELECT *
            ,RANK() OVER  (PARTITION BY F.[WorkshopId], F.[Date_of_Work] ORDER BY F.[Date_Import] DESC) AS Ranking  
            FROM DWH.Fact F    
            ) Inter
        WHERE Ranking = 1
        )BA         
        on BA.WorkshopId = S.WorkshopId and BA.Date_of_Work = S.Date_of_Work 

    where BA.Fact_KEY is not null
        and BA.WorkforceNeeded != convert(int,S.WorkforceNeeded)
        and BA.Date_Import = GETDATE()
end

----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- INSERT
----------------------------------------------------------------------
begin

    insert into DWH.Fact(
        [WorkshopId]
        ,[Date_Import]
        ,[Date_of_Work]
        ,[WorkforceNeeded])
    Select 
            ISNULL(A.WorkshopId,-1) as WorkshopId,
            GETDATE() Date_Import,
            S.Date_of_Work as [Date_of_Work],
            Convert(int,S.WorkforceNeeded) as WorkforceNeeded
    from Staging S 
        left outer join
        (
        SELECT *
        FROM    (
            SELECT *
            ,RANK() OVER  (PARTITION BY F.[WorkshopId], F.[Date_of_Work] ORDER BY F.[Date_Import] DESC) AS Ranking  
            FROM DWH.Fact F    
            ) Inter
        WHERE Ranking = 1
        )BA         
        on BA.WorkshopId = S.WorkshopId and BA.Date_of_Work = S.Date_of_Work

    where 
        (
        BA.Fact_KEY is null
        ) 
        OR 
        (
        BA.Fact_KEY is not null
        and BA.Date_Import != GETDATE()
        and BA.WorkforceNeeded != convert(int,S.WorkforceNeeded)
        )

end
```

Edited example.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using an `INNER JOIN` not a `LEFT JOIN` for the `UPDATE`. If you post the SQL you've written, that'll be really helpful.

Comment: Have you looked into `Merge`?

Comment: `MERGE` would be a good tool too; provided the OP isn't (still) using SQL Server 2008/R2. It was awful in those versions.

Comment: Great data example provided!

Comment: I have already use merge in another similar case. I was trying to avoid this fonction because I dont know what it really does. But in the other case it works just fine, I will maybe use this fonction if I don't have another solution.

Comment: @Balios - I see that you added a solution to your own problem in the question. Please consider adding it as an answer instead and check it as the solution for your question if it's what you went with.

Comment: I will do so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way that seems good using Merge. Does someone see another more effecient way to do it ?

```
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- UPDATE 
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        begin
            MERGE DWH.Fact AS TARGET
            USING Staging AS SOURCE 

            -- champs à match 
            ON (TARGET.Date_of_Work = SOURCE.Date_of_Work) 
                AND (TARGET.WorkshopId = SOURCE.WorkshopId) 

            --When records are matched, update the records if there is any change
            WHEN MATCHED  AND TARGET.Date_Import = SOURCE.Date_Import AND TARGET.WorkforceNeeded <> SOURCE.WorkforceNeeded THEN 
            UPDATE SET 
                TARGET.WorkforceNeeded = SOURCE.WorkforceNeeded
            ;
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- INSERT 
        ----------------------------------------------------------------------
            MERGE DWH.Fact AS TARGET
            USING Staging AS SOURCE 
            -- champs à match 
            ON (TARGET.Date_of_Work = SOURCE.Date_of_Work) AND (TARGET.WorkshopId = SOURCE.WorkshopId) AND (TARGET.WorkforceNeeded = SOURCE.WorkforceNeeded)  

            --When no records are matched, insert the incoming records from source table to target table
            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
            INSERT (Date_of_Work, WorkshopId, Date_Import, WorkforceNeeded)
            VALUES (SOURCE.Date_of_Work ,SOURCE.WorkshopId ,SOURCE.Date_Import ,SOURCE.WorkforceNeeded)
        ;

    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `MERGE`. I tried with your above data example and this worked for me:

```
MERGE Fact as target
USING Staging as source
ON (source.WorkshopId = target.WorkshopId AND source.Date_Import = target.Date_Import)
--If WorkshopId and Date_Import and Date_of_Work has a match, then update
WHEN MATCHED AND source.Date_of_Work = target.Date_of_Work THEN
    UPDATE SET target.WorkforceNeeded = source.WorkforceNeeded
--If not, insert instead
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Date_Import, Date_of_Work, WorkshopId, WorkforceNeeded) VALUES (Date_Import, Date_of_Work, WorkshopId, WorkforceNeeded);
```

What this does is it checks if `WorkshopId`, `Date_Import` and `Date_of_Work` has a match and makes an update on the `WorkforceNeeded`. If there is no match it makes an insert instead. 
Be sure to run this in a test-environment or within `begin/rollback transaction` just to be sure. Allso `MERGE` is not supportet until SQL Server 2008 and later.

Here is some more information on the `MERGE` statement: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017